# Solving equations with complex parameters

Tags: equation-solving

I am a beginner at Mathematica. I found a few questions that were related to this one but none of them was solving the problem.

I want to solve the following system:

$$W = S^2 + s^2$$

$$X = P^2 + p^2$$

$$Y = S\cdot P - i\cdot S \cdot p + i\cdot s \cdot P + s \cdot p$$

$$Z = S\cdot P + i\cdot S \cdot p - i\cdot s \cdot P + s \cdot p$$

where $(W,X,Y,Z)$ are complex parameters and $(S, P, s, p)$ are the unknowns and are all real.

I tried the following:

```
Solve[{S^2 + s^2 == W, 
       P^2 + p^2 == X, 
       S*P - I*S*p + I*P*s + s*p == Y, 
       S*P + I*S*p - I*P*s + s*p == Z}, {S,s,P,p}, Reals]
```

But the output is the following :

```
The system contains a nonreal constant i. With the domain R speicifed, all constants should be real.
```

If I do the same without putting the `Reals` command, or setting it to `Complexes`, the output is `{}`.

Comment: "S*P + I*S*p - I*P*s" is not an equation. Further  "s*p == Y" and  s*p == Z does not seem right.

Comment: Thanks you're right. I did the mistake by writing it here but not in Mathematica. It's correct now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must give the domains in the equations, otherwise it is assumed that all variables are real.

The output of "{}" means that there is no general solution.
Use "Reduce", that can deal with solutions that are only valid under certain conditions.

Here is the working code:

```
Reduce[{S^2 + s^2 == W, P^2 + p^2 == X, 
  S*P - I*S*p + I*P*s + s*p == Y, 
  S*P + I*S*p - I*P*s + s*p == Z, {W, X, Y, Z} \[Element] 
   Complexes, {S, P, s, p} \[Element] Reals}, {S, s, P, p}]
```

The output is too lengthy to include here.

Comment: `{W, X, Y, Z} \[Element] Complexes` is unnecessary since symbols are considered complex unless otherwise specified. The results are identical with or without this constraint.